# Execute a command in the terminal from Netlogo

Tags: terminal, netlogo

I hope you can help me with this.

I'm new to Netlogo and I would like to execute a command line from Netlogo. I've been looking but I haven't find yet how to do it. Does anyone know a way?

Thank you a lot in advance.

Best,
Miquel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use NetLogo's `shell` extension for this:
https://github.com/NetLogo/Shell-Extension